# ConEmu opening new window instead of tab

Tags: console, conemu

I am currently using the stable version of ConEmu (120727) and I am having an issue with the “ConEmu Here” functionality.

Whenever I click the option within the Windows Explorer context menu, it always opens a new windows instead of opening a new tab within an existing ConEmu instance.

The latest Alpha version has a “Single Instance” mode which fixes this issue however I get the feeling that such functionality should just work even in the older stable version given the fact that I am using a -`cur_console` flag on the registered command for “ConEmu Here“ and there's even an option to take over a new cmd window and attach it to ConEmu automatically.

Has anybody had a similar issue or know how it is—or it is not—supposed to work?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/963826/conemu-how-to-attach-putty - this solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting `Settings > Main > Appearance > Multiple consoles in one ConEmu window`

Answer (score 1):

cur_console is not the switch you needed.
Try `/single` switch in the command line for "Here" item.
However I always recommend trying last alpha versions, because many issues were fixed already and testing of the new features is required.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding /Single to the "Here" section and it still does not work. I should note that I tested this even on the latest Alpha version and it does not work without enabling "Single Instance" mode