# ConEmu: How to attach PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, conemu

I have been trying to open a new PuTTY window inside as one of ConEmu Tab, but no success so far, I've tried many combinations.

```
putty.exe -cur_console:b -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
putty.exe -new_console -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd putty.exe -cur_console:b -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
ConEmuC.exe /ATTACH /ROOT putty.exe -cur_console:b -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
```

what will happen is putty will be open in a new window outside ConEmu

Comment: see my answer - it is valid and functional https://superuser.com/a/1681413/1024056

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue, as I installed PUTTY by [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org). 
In this case, if you call PUTTY, it will run the shim from the *chocolatey\bin* folder, and not the real exe.

As I put the whole path into the task, PUTTY appeared within the ConEmu window:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\putty.portable\tools\PUTTY.EXE -load "saved session"
```

Comment: Similar issue here after using Scoop to install PuTTy.

Similarly, I had to change the task to run from the scoop apps directory. i.e.
C:\Users\<username>\scoop\apps\putty\current\PUTTY.EXE -load "saved session"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with putty launching a new window even when I was able to get notepad to work correctly and found your question in looking for a solution. I was later able to solve the problem as per below.

In the [settings dialog](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html) for your command, under task parameters provide the following:

```
/dir <full path to your instance of putty>
```

Then in the Commands box provide something like this:

```
putty.exe -cur_console -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
```

This should work. In my case I'm using something more along the lines of this:

```
putty.exe -cur_console -load <profile name>
```

If you want something you can just type in on the command line then something like this should work:

```
putty.exe -new_console:d"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\PuTTY" -ssh USER@DOMAIN 22 -pw PASSWORD
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason, it's still not working for me :(
On the putty tab on conemu, it's showing this message:

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode-0
Press Enter or Esc to close console....

It will open putty on a separate window outside of ConEmu

Comment: @kjv.007 updated with another option

Comment: @Julian Can you share a Figure about what you added in "settings dialog"? - I can see the current figure, but not sure what you added

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is the full path inside quotes

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "your_session_Name"
```

Any thing else opened putty in a seperate window.

ConEmu  version: 160724 32 bit. PuTTY Release 0.67 32 bit

Comment: This worked for me as well, granted I had already set up my profile

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Putting the PuTTY path inside double quotes makes it work correctly.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me too.

Comment: Even when it works, it opens a new window. The point is do the connection within the ConEmu

Answer (score 3):

The **solution** is, open the [Task](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html) section, add a new task:

- Give a name: for example `PuTTY SSH 192.168.1.X`
- Leave empty the textfield (the second)
- In the textarea (in the bottom) add **one** of the following commands according your preference:

```
C:\path-to-putty\putty.exe -ssh username@192.168.1.X
C:\path-to-putty\putty.exe -load "saved session name"
```

Do click at `Save settings`

Therefore, with `ConEmu` still running proceed to open a *New console dialog...* (or `Win + Shift + W`), it opens a new dialog window, in the first select box search the `PuTTY SSH 192.168.1.X` option and do click in the `Start` button and done!

Therefore with this approach you are able to:

- Open in the same window many tabs to establish a connection for the same remote machine
- Create many tasks as you need where each task represents a different connection to other remote machine

Answer (score 2):

Just created a new ConEmu task with the following command:

```
PUTTY.EXE -cur_console -ssh <Login>@<HostAddress> -pw <Password>
```

works like a charm.

Comment: for me it's just showing these in my ConEmu Tab

`ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...`

and then opening the usual putty window seperately.